# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar un file.sh de forma remota desde otro file.sh?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, ssh, sh

Tengo un clúster pequeño y tengo un script bash en un archivo .sh en un nodo donde intento ejecutar algunos comandos de forma remota, pero no funciona.  Cuando ejecuto los comandos individualmente en los nodos, funciona. Incluso cuando me conecto desde el nodo maestro a través de ssh a otros nodos, funciona. Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto el script bash (archivo .sh) desde el nodo maestro, no funciona.

Por ejemplo:

file.sh -> solo está en el nodo maestro:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -t root@192.168.1.45 bash file2.sh

exit
```

file2.sh -> está en todos los nodos excepto en el nodo maestro:

```
#!/bin/bash

if sqlplus -V; then
  echo "OK"
else
  echo "Error"
fi
exit
```

Ejecutando el script bash (archivo file.sh) desde el nodo maestro. Obtengo:

```
[cluster_master@localhost ~]$ bash file.sh
root@192.168.1.45's password:
file2.sh: línea 2: sqlplus: no se encontró la orden
Error
Connection to 192.168.1.45 closed.
[cluster_master@localhost ~]$
```

Conectándome a través de ssh a un nodo y ejecutando el script bash (archivo file2.sh) y luego el comando individualmente. Obtengo:

```
[cluster_master@localhost ~]$ ssh root@192.168.1.45
root@192.168.1.45's password:
Activate the web console with: systemctl enable --now cockpit.socket

Last login: Mon Dec  5 22:51:20 2022 from 192.168.1.32
[root@localhost ~]# bash file2.sh

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

OK
[root@localhost ~]# sqlplus -V

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

[root@localhost ~]#
```

Ejecutando directamente desde un nodo el script bash (archivo file2.sh) y luego el comando individualmente (lo mismo sucede en los otros nodos). Obtengo:

```
[root@localhost ~]# bash file2.sh
    
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
    
OK
[root@localhost ~]# sqlplus -V
    
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
    
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Tanto file.sh como file2.sh tienen permisos completos.

IP 192.168.1.32 -> El nodo maestro

IP 192.168.1.45 -> uno de los nodos

Quiero ejecutar el script bash (archivo file.sh) desde el nodo maestro y obtener el resultado que obtengo cuando me conecto a través de ssh a un nodo y ejecuto el script bash (archivo file2.sh) y luego el comando individualmente o como cuando estoy directamente en un nodo.

Sucede con cualquier comando, no solo con sqlplus. En el caso del comando sqlplus, se configuraron las variables de entorno.

Estoy usando Linux.

Comment: ponele el path ( remoto ) completo al .sh tipo `/home/scripts/file2.sh`, conviene meterlos todos en su propia carpeta y/o con un usuario específico; para habilitar ciertos comando a que corran como root usando sudo sin clave editas el archivo `/etc/sudoers` o creas un archivo en `/etc/sudoers.d/` según la versión del sistema

Comment: @aloMalbarez, gracias. Pero intenté lo que propones y aún sigo obteniendo el error "no se encontró la orden". Lo de la propia carpeta, si, eso va que va, eso lo tengo en cuenta para cuando termine el programa.

Comment: puede ser redundante segun la config proba con  `ssh -t root@192.168.1.45 ". ~/.profile ; bash file2.sh"`

Comment: La respuesta de @aloMalbarez y la mía tocan el mismo punto: tienes problemas de que tu namespace no detecta las variables de entorno necesarias. Mientras alo te sugiere cargar tus archivos de configuración durante el string-command a ejecutar, yo te sugiero que tomes las variables necesarias y las pegues en tu archivo nodo. Pero nuestro punto sigue teniendo la misma raíz: carga las variables de entorno necesarias ante de ejecutar tu programa.

Comment: @aloMalbarez, gracias. Haciéndole el source al archivo de configuración correspondiente donde tengo mis variables de entorno, funciona. Y aunque lo que menciona Cuauhtli, también funciona, veo que es algo redundante volver a definir y exportar la variables que ya tengo definidas en el archivo de configuración. Pero las dos soluciones son validas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple vista siento que es una cosa de las variables de entorno dentro de tu script.

Es decir, cuando entras manualmente a tu usuario, tienes acceso a ciertas variables de entorno añadidas que fueron leídas de dentro de archivos como `.bashrc` o `.profile`. Pero dentro de tu script NO tienes acceso.

Repito, ingresando como usuario SI tienes acceso a esas variables de entorno, pero ejecutando el script con `ssh` NO tienes acceso a esas variables.

Intenta con que en cada script definas la variable `PATH` con las carpetas que tienen los archivos necesarios. Por ejemplo:

file2.sh:

```bash
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:<y otras que estén en tu variable PATH cuando ingresas al nodo>
...
```

Esta es una opción, otra es que cuando ejecutes el programa `sqlplus`, utilices la ruta entera a su ejecutable:

```
if /usr/local/bin/sqlplus -V; then
```

**Esto suponiendo que sqlplus se encuentra en esa ruta**. Para asegurarte, dentro del nodo2 ejecuta `command -v sqlplus` o `which sqlplus`. Y de ahí te puedes guiar para o construir tu variable `PATH`, o añadir a tu archivo del nodo2.

Y claro, como te dicen en los comentarios, trata de usar rutas absolutas para correr tus scripts. Así evitas ambiguedad:

```
ssh -t root@192.168.1.45 "bash /root/file2.sh"
```

Además, como muchos de los script que corres dependen de tus variables de entorno, también te podría ayudar ver los archivos de inicialización de tus nodos para ver qué más le inyectan a la variable PATH o que otras variables de entorno tienen. Me refiero a archivos como `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, `.aliases`, `.profile`, `.bash_profile`.

### Update

Es decir, para correr tu script en el nodo esclavo desde el nodo maestro, necesitarías definir dentro del script del nodo esclavo las variables que vas a requerir para tu programa, por ejemplo:

```bash
#[START] Estas son las variables
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin...etc 
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/...etc
export ORACLE_HOME=...
#[END] Estas son las variables

(...) El resto de tu script
```

Esto lo puedes hacer entrando como siempre al usuario de tu nodo donde todo corre bien, y ahí imprimir el contenido de tu variable PATH: `echo $PATH`, además de copiando y pegando las variables que tienes declaradas en tus archivos .bashrc, .profile, entre otros, que creas que te puedan servir.

Por ejemplo, abres con `vim`, `nano`, `less`, o cualquier editor/visor de texto `node-user$ vim .bashrc`:

```
# Comentarios
# Mas comentarios
export MAVEN_HOME=... # <---- copias esto si lo crees necesario
export JAVA_HOME=... # <---- o esto si lo crees necesario

export PATH=$PATH:/<otras rutas> # <--- Esto también
```

Y eso que copiaste de esos archivos que creiste necesario, lo pegas dentro de tu script `file2.sh` en tu nodo **ANTES DE CORRER TODO TU SCRIPT PRINCIPAL**.

Comment: gracias por responder. La variable PATH ya se configura antes de ejecutar el comando, en este caso, sqlplus. Lo que estoy haciendo es una automatización para instalar oracle en todos los nodos; al final, la idea es que se muestre un reporte de si si se instaló o hubo algún error en alguno de los nodos. Este error lo obtengo es al final del programa cuando valido en cada nodo.
Y no solo sucede con el comando sqlplus, también si uso which sqlplus, obtengo el mismo error. Y lo curioso es que solo sucede si lo ejecuto desde un bash local que a su vez ejecuta el bash del nodo remoto.

Comment: Si ejecuto el comando o el bash individualmente en cada nodo, funciona. Igualmente, si me conecto desde el nodo master via ssh y ejecuto, funciona.

Comment: Ni siquiera poniendo la ruta completa funciona. Sin embargo, obtengo un nuevo error: 

Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus

SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found

SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory

Ese error no me había aparecido. Lo investigaré.

La variable ORACLE_HOME ya la tengo configurada, incluso para todos los usuarios lo he intentado. Eso lo hago en /etc/profile. También para cada usuario especifico lo hago en .bash_profile

Comment: Como puse en mi respuesta, eso de la variable `ORACLE_HOME`, sigue siendo un problema de las variables de entorno. Si se cargan cuando obtienes una shell en tu usuario, pero no cuando ejecutas ssh. Entonces esas variables defínelas DENTRO de tu script del nodo.

Comment: Es decir, mi punto principal es que considero que siempre fue un problema de variables de entorno (primero el PATH, y ahora ORACLE_HOME) que NO se cargaron en tu script como normalmente se cargan cuando ingresas al nodo manualmente. Por lo tanto, DENTRO de tu script del nodo, DECLARA Y EXPORTA TODAS LAS VARIABLES DE ENTORNO QUE NECESITES: el PATH adecuado más las que se usen de tu .bashrc y /etc/profile.

Comment: Listo, @RonaldCorrea. Actualicé mi respuesta para ser más claro.

Comment: Como lo mencioné, en el script se hace toda la instalación de oracle, y con ello la configuración de esas variables de entorno.
Tienes razón al decir que el problema es de variables de entorno; y si funciona como dices, pero no veo que tenga que volverlas a definir como propones ya que ya las tengo en los archivos de configuración. De hecho, @alo Malbarez sugirió cargar el archivo de configuración en el string-command; de esa manera también funcionó, y de hecho, la veo mas viable ya que se usa menos código. Sin embargo, noto que no te gusta esa idea, ¿por qué?

Comment: y ¿por qué ejecutando el script con ssh NO tengo acceso a esas variables?

Comment: No sólo no las vuelves a definir, sino que las defines por primera vez. La shell que corres cuando haces el one-liner con ssh no carga por defecto los archivos .bashrc, .profile, etc. Eso lo haces cuando entras directamente a tu terminal.

Comment: Mi asunto con cargar todo es con un `source`, es que si por cada script sencillo vas a cargar tooodas las configuraciones para ver cuál es la que pega, llenaras ese proceso tanto con variables que puede que no necesites (que pueden ser pocas o muchas), o configuraciones extras de otros módulos que no necesites.

Comment: Eso tiene el potencial de volver pesado tu entorno de ejecución, lleno de paja. Y si, osea, te va a funcionar pero es medio cuestionable el cómo lo haga. En cambio si defines (que es por primera vez) las variables y recursos específicos, y ,por qué no, hasta los parámetros de entrada de tu script, literal ya estás dando un super buen paso en las tareas de un ingeniero de DevOps :)

Comment: De hecho, no sé si haz trabajado con Docker o con docker-compose. Esos sistemas de automatización funcionan pasándole las variables de entorno, parámetros, y recursos que vas a necesitar. Esos recursos y variables y no otros más que puedan desde ofuscar la depuración y desarrollo, hasta sobrecargar el proceso del worker.

Comment: Comprendo tu punto, bastante interesante y útil, y si, he visto como funciona Docker, es una buena analogía para lo que planteas. ¡¡Muchas gracias!!, lo tendré en cuenta. 